# Скачать изображение по url

Tags: php

Есть xls документ в котором идут ссылки на изображения (2000 строк )на сторонний ресурс
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я скопировал все ссылки и поместил в блокнот и поместил его на сервер.

```
$imageUrl = './bb.txt';
$imageFilePath = './img/'.foto.'.jpg'; // вопрос тут.как ставить оригинальное имя изображения?
file_put_contents($imageFilePath, file_get_contents($imageUrl));
```

Если ставлю имя фото которое будет ему присвоено например foto, то скачивает только 1 фото. а мне нужно скопом.

делал случайным имя случайным образом

```
 $ran= substr(uniqid('', true), -5); 
$imageUrl = './bb.txt';
 $imageFilePath = './img/'.$ran.'.jpg'; 
file_put_contents($imageFilePath, file_get_contents($imageUrl));
```

все равно скачивает только 1 фото. пример откуда скачать файлы здесь badja94f.beget.tech/bb.txt

Comment: Создайте массив _(список с именами фото)_ и обрабатывайте его в цикле.

Comment: Задайте имена счетчиком, в чем проблема

Comment: я не силен в php.  мне нужны оригинальные имена

Comment: делал `$ran= substr(uniqid('', true), -5);
$imageUrl = './bb.txt';
$imageFilePath = './img/'.$ran.'.jpg'; 
file_put_contents($imageFilePath, file_get_contents($imageUrl));` все равно скачивает только 1 фото. пример здесь http://badja94f.beget.tech/bb.txt

Comment: Дополнительную информацию нужно добавлять в вопрос. Код в комментариях никто читать не будет, потому что он нечитаем.

Comment: Если вы не знаете что такое циклы, то скорее всего вы вообще не сильны в программировании. На заметку почитайте (http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сперва собираете ссылки на фото в массив:

```
$photos = [
    'https://partners.eksmo.ru/images/ishopcover/ITD000000000317230_cover1.jpg',
    'https://partners.eksmo.ru/images/ishopcover/ITD000000000242165_cover1.jpg',
    'https://partners.eksmo.ru/images/ishopcover/ITD000000000323557_cover1.jpg',
    'https://partners.eksmo.ru/images/ishopcover/ITD000000000291758_cover1.jpg',
    'https://partners.eksmo.ru/images/ishopcover/ITD000000000480406_cover1.jpg',
    'https://partners.eksmo.ru/images/ishopcover/ITD000000000163903_cover1.jpg'
];

foreach ($photos as $i => $photo) {
    $imageFilePath = './img/photo_'. ++$i .'.jpg';
    file_put_contents($imageFilePath, file_get_contents($photo));
}
```

По окончании работы скрипта в папке `img` появятся картинки с именами `photo_1.jpg`, `photo_2.jpg`, `photo_3.jpg`
и т.д.

---

**UPD:**
С учётом уточнений из комментариев:

```
$url = 'http://badja94f.beget.tech/bb.txt';
$photos = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($url));

foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    $fname = './img' . substr($photo, strripos($photo, '/'));
    file_put_contents($fname, file_get_contents($photo));
}
```

Comment: cкачивает только 3 изображения,при этом у всех скачанный размер 0 байт и имена у них не оригинальные

Comment: вот от сюда нужно по ссылкам скачать badja94f.beget.tech/bb.txt

Comment: нет,хочу чтобы из этого файла по ссылкам которые там указаны скачивались изображения

Comment: +с оригинальным именем изображения,который у них имеется в этих ссылках

Comment: Эдуард  ,спасибо, заработало.у меня просто в файле будут по 2000-3000 тысячи изображений. думал чтобы ссылки считывались из блокнота.а как сделать чтобы имена изображений были такие же как в файле, например ITD000000000317230_cover1

Comment: спасибо,буду ждать. отметил

Comment: Почти) только сохраняет не в папке img и скачанные файлы весят 0 байт. при попытке открыть  с сервера эти фото пишет '{"message": "('Unsafe header value %r', b'/tmp/fm/everest4.beget:9443/badja94f/5dd2f6cedb8cf4b44d2f139c6ccf313c/ITD000000000291758_cover1.jpg\\r')"}'

Comment: @AndreyVladimirovich дописал название папки ) На счёт ответа сервера - скорее всего curl-ом нужно будет получать строку с набором ссылок, или если это json, то распарсить её.

Comment: Столкнулся с похожим вопросом, все сделал, только сейчас остался момент - как собрать эти фото в массив? Я пробовал через $images = explode(', ', $file);